# UISplitview Initial state within tabbarcontroller in portrait

Tags: ios5, storyboard, tabbarcontroller, uisplitview

I have a similar problem as stated in this thread: [iPad UISplitView initial state in portrait: how to display popover controller widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754666/ipad-uisplitview-initial-state-in-portrait-how-to-display-popover-controller-wi)

The issue is that when my app starts in portrait mode the button for the masterview of the splitview does not show. In the thread mentioned above the solution was to porgrammatically assign the splitview as the window's rootviewcontroller.
For me this will not work as I have my splitview within a tabbarcontroller and that is the rootviewcontroller. Furthermore I have another splitview under a different tab and that has the same issue. 
When I rotate the iPad to landscape and back the button appears, but I have to do that for both tabs individually. Also, the button only appears on the device not in the simulator.

Does anyone have a way to trigger the splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController: ?

I am working from a storyboard in iOS 5, iPad only.